# Variable length arrow with FabricJS Path()

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a variable length arrow in fabric.js using Path().

`new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 150 0 M 0 0 L 10 -10 M 0 0 L 10 10 z', {});`

This creates a fixed length arrow, but I'd like it to work as follows:

- click on canvas, arrow tip appears (keep mouse down and drag to endposition)
- when you drag the arrow to endposition the line gets longer but tip stays the same size
- still while dragging the line stays attached to the point of origin and the whole arrow rotates around it until dragging stops

Can this be done? And how would you create this functionality?

Help appreciated!

**Edit:**

Found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7a5Ms/51/ which basically is what I'm looking for, but the calculation of the arrow angle is off. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the code working from the fiddle.